# A better way to detect the cursor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Goal: Detect when the cursor has entered a defined radius of the player.

Hello, I am in the process of trying to replicate the combat system from a game called CrossCode. The idea is that when the cursor is within a certain radius of the player, I will be able to switch to melee combat, and back to ranged once the cursor leaves this radius.

I have implemented one way I thought it could be done, however it feels slow or unreliable and I just wanted to know if there are any other methods I could possibly look into to achieve a smoother result.

Here is what I've done

attached to the player

```
void Update()
{
    attackStyleSwitchRadius = colRef.radius;
    playerCenter = colRef.transform.position;

    if(Physics2D.OverlapCircle(playerCenter, attackStyleSwitchRadius, cursor))
    {
        meleeMode = true;
        rangeMode = false;
    }
    else
    {
        meleeMode = false;
        rangeMode = true;
    }

}
```

And on a small 2D object I have this script so that it follows the cursor position.

```
void Update()
{
    pos = Input.mousePosition;
    gameObject.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
}
```

when the small object enters the overlap circle it changes the bools around.

Comment: can't you use a Spherecollider and Raycasting? Also you may want to use `PreUpdate` for moving the "CursorObject", otherwise the object may be move bevore or after the other Update.

Comment: I see, I never even thought of that. I will give it a go now, and I am unsure of what `PreUpdate` is, I will try `FixedUpdate` because I think it will be better than regular update in this scenario.

Comment: FixedUpdate will not help, I think. `PreUpdate` and `Uptate` should solve your "unreliability".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the collision detection overhead by doing something like this instead;

```
void Update ()
{
    attackStyleSwitchRadius = colRef.radius;
    playerCenter = colRef.transform.position;

    var mouse = Input.mousePosition;
    mouse.z = Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, playerCenter);

    var range = Vector2.Distance(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mouse), playerCenter);    
    var inside = range < attackStyleSwitchRadius;

    meleeMode = inside;
    rangeMode = !inside;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Cursor**

1. Make an object, name it cursor.
2. Add a small collider to the cursor object.
3. Add a script to the cursor object so its always at the mouses location.

**Melee range zone**

4. Add a GameObject as child of the player, name it MeleeRangeZone.
5. Add a collider to it, set it to be a Trigger. The size of this collider will be the players melee range,
6. Add a rigidbody to it so that collisions can be detected, but set the rigidbody to not rotate or change its position.
7. Add a script to the object and use the OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit methods to detect whether or not the cursor has entered your melee zone.

You can now use the OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit methods to switch between the players attack modes, meaning that when the cursor enters it changes to melee and when it exit it changes to ranged.

You can fire the ray to detect the location the cursor should have like this:

```
public LayerMask RaycastCollidableLayers;
public RaycastHit Hit;
public float CheckDistance = 200f;
public Transform Cursor;

void PerformRaycast(){
//Set up ray
ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
//Fire ray
Physics.Raycast(ray, out Hit, CheckDistance + 0.1f, RaycastCollidableLayers);
if (Hit.collider == null)
{
    //Debug.Log("Raycast hit nothing");
    return;
}
else //Ray hit something
    {
    //Move cursor to Hit.point;
    Cursor.position = Hit.point;
    }
}
```

Comment: May or may not be the best method, but I like the ingenuity of it!

Comment: Thank you :-). I believe the method will work. It also has the added benefit of automatically showing a visible radius.

Comment: I actually like this method a little better than the accepted answer because it should work on all screen resolutions in the same way.

Comment: What would prevent the accepted answer from working on all resolutions?

Comment: It wouldn't fail, it would just be inconsistent because they're basing the range check on pixel distances(if I'm understanding correctly), which will be different for different screen resolutions. i.e. 100px on a 1080p screen may be 1 unity unit, while 100px on a 2160p screen might be .25 unity units. I believe you could also resize the window to accomplish a similar effect, instead of using different screen resolutions.

Comment: Ah yes, I believe you are right that it may be inconsistent as it isn't inside world space.

Comment: @Doh09 I would add your ray implementation to this answer as well, make sure to use a LayerMask to help make the ray less expensive.

Comment: @Eddge I added an example with that in to the answer. Had thought about it but your comment made me add it.